# Decode raydium transaction

Tags: solana-program

Does anyone know how to decode the data of a transaction involving the raydium app?

Here's an example:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"programNotification","params":{"result":{"context":{"slot":240296362},"value":{"pubkey":"Ggtb5fAiFrD3Ft7MktLWZfV2ASvQGXhVhotvGvU53jFD","account":{"lamports":6124800,"data":["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","base64"],"owner":"675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8","executable":false,"rentEpoch":0,"space":752}}},"subscription":136714}}
```